# JavaScript TrafficLights image change not working

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an investigation project at school and I need to make traffic lights in JavaScript. I have got PNG images of the different stages in a traffic light and I want to switch between them when a button is clicked. This is what I have written but I cant seem to find any mistakes. This is the first time I'm doing JavaScript and I am on a time limit. Please respond ASAP

thank you very much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <script>
        var lights = [
            "Assets/TrafficLight1.png",
            "Assets/TrafficLight2.png",
            "Assets/TrafficLight3.png",
            "Assets/TrafficLight4.png"
        ];

        var i = 0;
        function ChangeLights() {
            document.getElementById("TrafficLight1").src = lights[i];

            if (i = 4) {
                i = 0;
            } else {
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
    </script>

    <button onclick="ChangeLights()">Click To Change</button>
    <img src ="Assets/TrafficLight1.png" alt="trafficlight" name="TrafficLight1" width ="200"  height= "400" id="TrafficLight1">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
if (i = 4) {
```

This is incorrect, becouse it's assigning 4 to i, so it's always true - 4 is truthy value. Use `===`:

```
if (i === 4) {
```

Comment: thank you very much I didn't realise it was such a simple fix :D

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using the if logic comparison wrong.

Change `if (i = 4) {` 
to 
`if (i === 4) {`.

So using one (1)(=) sign sets the variable to the value.

Using two (2)(==) does a comparison.

Using three (3)(===) does a direct comparison.